# how to achive the string effects like http://www.bcaa.it/

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I wanna do a string effect like this website http://www.bcaa.it/
What kind of script or tutorial can I learn from?

Basically I want to achieve same as the website. Have the bouncing string effects, drag the item and move away others item that near it, drag and the sub object follow with easing...

Comment: Do you mean you just want to draw a line that attaches two elements?

Comment: Yah like that website, when you click on 1 object, it will come out another object that with strings and attach with the main object. And when drag the main object around, the sub-objects is following with easing/bouncing. Any tutorial I can follow?

Comment: Including the circles, line drawing and bounce tweening is making this question rather broad. I can write an answer that covers drawing a line between two moving objects.

Answer (score 1):

Hey just started coding this up, need something similar for a graph display I'm working on.  Here's my start, just two buttons but the idea could be extrapolated/optimized:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var optimalDistanceUpdateTimer:Timer;

            private var optimalDistance:Number = 100;

            private var objectUserGrabbed:Button;

            private var delayDenominator:Number = 6;

            protected function button1_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                objectUserGrabbed = event.target as Button;
                objectUserGrabbed.startDrag();
            }

            protected function button1_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                objectUserGrabbed.stopDrag();
            }

            protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                optimalDistanceUpdateTimer = new Timer(33);
                optimalDistanceUpdateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, optimalDistanceTickedHandler);
                optimalDistanceUpdateTimer.start();
            }
            private function optimalDistanceTickedHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
            {
                var targetPoint:Point;
                var deltaX:Number;
                var deltaY:Number;

                if(!objectUserGrabbed)
                    return;

                if(objectUserGrabbed == button1)
                {
                    //Basically here I'm playing of Pythagorean theorem for a 45 degree triangle the x component and the y component are the distance of the hypotenuse over Sqrt(2) for different offsets, radially you'd need to adjust this to compute the target point for each object... would do something like var angleForEach:Number = 360/numObjects; then figure out the target point for each of the objects in a loop var angleForThis = angleForEach*index; (in this example only two objects, no loop needed)
                    targetPoint = new Point(objectUserGrabbed.x-optimalDistance/Math.SQRT2, objectUserGrabbed.y-optimalDistance/Math.SQRT2);


                    deltaX = (targetPoint.x-button2.x);
                    deltaY = (targetPoint.y-button2.y);

                    button2.move(button2.x+deltaX/delayDenominator, button2.y+deltaY/delayDenominator);
                }
                else
                {
                    targetPoint = new Point(objectUserGrabbed.x+optimalDistance/Math.SQRT2, objectUserGrabbed.y + optimalDistance/Math.SQRT2);

                    deltaX = (targetPoint.x-button1.x);
                    deltaY = (targetPoint.y-button1.y);

                    button1.move(button1.x+deltaX/delayDenominator, button1.y+deltaY/delayDenominator);
                }
                lineDrawingArea.graphics.clear();
                lineDrawingArea.graphics.lineStyle(1);
                lineDrawingArea.graphics.moveTo(button1.x + button1.width/2,button1.y + button1.height/2);
                lineDrawingArea.graphics.lineTo(button2.x + button2.width/2,button2.y + button2.height/2);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Group id="lineDrawingArea"/>
    <s:Button id="button1" label="Item 1" mouseDown="button1_mouseDownHandler(event)" mouseUp="button1_mouseUpHandler(event)" x="0" y="0"/>
    <s:Button id="button2" label="Item 2" mouseDown="button1_mouseDownHandler(event)" mouseUp="button1_mouseUpHandler(event)" x="0" y="0"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: oops sorry that I din mention that I just familiar with Flash AS3 only, but is it I can implement your code to AS3?

Comment: @pizza0502 yeah you can implement this code in AS3 pure without much issue... the startDrag/stopDrag exist on Sprite, pretty much everything here is available in Flash, sans Flex.  Instead of using creation complete, you'd probably want to handle that code in the constructor, otherwise this should be a pretty good starting point, will show one object connected to another with a line and where when one object is dragged the other, "chases" with a delay.  To extend this concept further you'd have to deal with a set of objects instead of just two.

Comment: @pizza0502 basically the problem I hit here is that now this is in pretty good shape for me to continue work on it using my own data structures (a graph implementation) to populate this line network, so the remainder of the work I do on this will be geared towards how I want it to work for my implementation/data structures. You'd have to come up with the data-structure/value object setup to store the data for all the "nodes" in some way that makes sense for this interaction (parent -> children, where parent has property for isOpen).

Comment: Also to note the Group object I'm using just as a simple means in Flex 4 to have "layer" with graphics I can draw to (it does no drawing on it's own and is much like a Canvas in Flex 3, or Sprite in AS3), this could easily be a sprite, the two buttons could be Sprites as well or MovieClips whatever you have to drag around (so long as it extends from Sprite).